# How do display managers log a user in?

Tags: login, display-manager, login-manager

I'm about to start working on my own display/login manager. I think I'll be able to handle all of the X11 stuff, but I realized I have no clue what to do when the user types in their username and password.

Once a display manager has a username and password, what does it do? How does it log you in? Are there any other specific requirements a login manager has to do, like sourcing any configuration files, or is that all left up to the desktop environment?

Comment: I guess you have to deal with PAM authentication and setting up the XAuth stuff. Probably execute the Xsession files too... You can get some hints from [SLIM (Simple Login Manager)](http://git.berlios.de/cgi-bin/cgit.cgi/slim/tree/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've made some progress on understanding this question, so I'll post what I know here. This answer is currently for those systems that use [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/). I'll add more on other methods of login as I encounter them.

After you type in your username and password into the fields of your display manager, the display manager takes these two fields and starts the PAM authentication process.

First it calls `pam_start()`. This tells PAM which conversation function (we'll get to what that is) you're using and what `pam_handle_t` struct to initialize. You pass this `pam_handle_t` struct into all of the following calls.

Then you can set any properties like the username using `pam_set_item()`. You don't have to set the username here. When you call `pam_authenticate()`, it will ask for any information it doesn't already have.

Next you call `pam_authenticate()` to see if the username and password are valid. At this point, `pam_authenticate()` gets any information it didn't have using the [conversation function](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-interface-of-app-expected.html#adg-pam_conv). You can look at that link for the details, but in short, PAM will call the conversation function you provided in the struct passed to `pam_start()` once you've called `pam_authenticate()`. It will then pass an array of messages to this conversation function. If the `msg_style` is `PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_ON`, it's asking for the username, and if the `msg_style` is `PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF`, it's asking for the password. The other two options are described in the spec and are used for error and informational messages. Depending on the message type, populate the `resp` array with the responses and return the correct error code.

Now if `pam_authenticate()` returns `PAM_SUCCESS`, that means the user exists. We then have to call `pam_acct_mgmt()` to make sure the user has permission to login at this time (I don't know where or how this permission is set).

At this point we get a token using `pam_setcred()` and then open a session with `pam_open_session()`. I don't know what the purpose of this is or how the token is actually used, but this is required. Let me know if you know more information.

Now we can set all of the bash variables we want using `pam_putenv()`. When our environment has everything we need, we can fork a new process, and then `exec` the `startx` command.

When this process finishes, the user is logging out. At this point we call `pam_close_session()`, `pam_setcred` (with the option to delete the credentials), and `pam_end()` in that order.

If any of this is incorrect or you have more information to add, please let me know. You can see [my display manager](https://github.com/gsingh93/display-manager) (still in development) for examples of this.